# Pip installation in command prompt

Tags: python-2.7

In command prompt, when running the command "python get-pip.py", the error "python was not found" was returned. The suggested solutions are to either install Python from the Microsoft Store or disable the app execution aliases shortcut from settings. What steps should I take next to resolve this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install pip on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-do-i-install-pip-on-windows)